# What is the set of numbers generated by this sieve called?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

The sieve of Eratosthenes' characterizes the set of prime numbers by sifting composite numbers from the set of natural numbers $> 2$.

Say we use the same sieve to instead sift all *perfect powers* from the set of natural numbers $>2$.

Does this set of numbers have a name?

The first $25$ numbers generated by the sieve would be:
$$
2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,28,29,30,31,33
$$

E.g., in Haskell I could define Eratosthenes' sieve as follows (where `diff` is an ordered list difference function, and `map` maps a function over a list):

```
multiples n = n : map (\ m -> m + n) (multiples n)
primes (n : ns) = n : diff (primes ns) (multiples n)
```

The sieve I have in mind is this:

```
powers n = n : map (\ m -> m * n) (powers n)
nonpowers (n : ns) = n : diff (nonpowers ns) (powers n)
```

Comment: non-powers? ${}$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I doubt that this sequence has a name. Moreover, what you mean by "sieving exponents" isn't clear to me. Please edit the question to show by example why $8$ as out but $12$ is in, why $24$ is out, ... (Don't respond with a comment - put more information into the question.)

Comment: @Wojowu that seems like a sensible name.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for the reply, and thanks for the suggestions. I've made some clarifying adjustments -- please let me know if you think the question needs more clarification.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A007916

Comment: @lhf Thanks. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is formed by the numbers that are not perfect powers: [OEIS/A007916](https://oeis.org/A007916).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're removing the perfect powers. In this case I don't think this particular set has a name.

Also, 24 should be in the remaining list, since it is not a perfect power.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I've updated the question.